# Rails: Locales using form_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, locale

How do I use locales and `form_with`? By locale I mean `/en` instead of `/?locale=en`.

This is part of my view file:

`<%= form_with(model: @model, local: true, locale: I18n.locale) do |form| %>`

After submitting the form I get the following error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"model_name", :format=>nil, :locale=>#<ModelName id: 2, created_at: "2018-10-15 11:07:36", updated_at: "2018-10-15 11:08:09">}, missing required keys: [:id], possible unmatched constraints: [:locale]`

Notice how locale is set with the given model ...

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
root 'model_name#new'

scope ':locale', locale: /[a-z]{2}/ do
  root 'model_name#new'
  resources :model_name, only: [:create, :show]
end
```

I don't understand why I need to set root twice but ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rails is using your instance of ModelName because locale isn't set.
To be sure that your locale is set in urls, add the `default_url_options` method to `application_controller`, where `set_locale` contains the logic for your application's locale.

```
def default_url_options
   { locale: set_locale }
end

private def set_locale
  params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests

Answer (score 1):

`root` inside of scope means the root of the scope.

Example:

```
root # matches / 
scope ':locale' do
  root # matches /en/
  resources :foos # matches /en/foos, /en/foo/1, ...
end
```

I suggest you to call `rake routes` to see what routes you have defined and play around a bit.

And back to the error you are getting. This error means, that the constraint on the scope is not matched. I'd bet, that the locale is empty. 
according to [docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) of `form_with`, you should use scope option, like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: @model, local: true, scope: I18n.locale) do |form| %>
```

Comment: scope actually has another use here, it will name the parameters passed by the form. What you suggest will create a locale[:field_name], which I think is not what the OP is looking for.